# Looking for a Python editor that will let me collapse functions

Tags: python

I really loved this feature when I used Eclipse for Java programming, but I can't find the same functionality for a Python editor. IDLE and Pyscripter are nice, but they don't help in this area.

Basically, I just want the option to collapse or otherwise hide functions that I don't feel like looking at for a while. Know of anything like this?

Comment: If you're using Eclipse already, you can install the PyDev plugin. See: http://pydev.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Geany](http://www.geany.org/) can do this.

Comment: I think I like Geany, but I can't seem to find an installer for the Debugger plugin. You wouldn't know anything about this, would you?

Comment: Try the generic plugins install executable. That should include all the plugins on that site, including geanygdb.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the aforementioned (great) editors, you might want to give [PyDev](http://pydev.org/) a shot as well.

Comment: Especially because the OP seems to like Eclipse, and PyDev is an Eclipse plug-in.

Answer (score 2):

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) has this feature.

Comment: I'll try this one as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Komodo Edit IDE](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit), *for Windows, Mac and Linux*, *for Python, PHP, Ruby, JavaScript, Perl and Web Dev*.

Answer (score 1):

I've used Komodo Edit and Notepad++ in the past but my current preference is [Sublime Text Edit 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2).

Although not free (and actually quite expensive), it can be used in free mode with only an occasional reminder and no other restrictions.

It is actually written in Python so you get a Python console built in - you can also get other consoles such as JavaScript. It is VERY flexible & has some very good features. It is also has an excellent community with loads of very useful plugins.

It is much lighter on resource usage than Komodo, can use Textmate bundles directly (so gets loads of formatting options for different file types). It is cross-platform and doesn't even need installation on Windows.

Comment: What about vim? It will allow folds.

Comment: Very true. Personally, I'm too graphically minded to really like VIM, even as gVIM. I do love the control you get from Sublime 2 though and I like that you can use Python and JS as scripting languages. It's all a matter of personal choice isn't it ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Pycharm** CE, from Jet Brains, indeed, wonderful. Functions and comments collapse is ready out of the box, as well as edit helpers. Project files and assets organization, integrated python console, powerful debugging tools,... Then, lots of plugins: git integration, tinycode view, extra languages' helpers and highlighters,.... anything you need when coding, but simple and easy to use. There's a Pro (paid) version for those who want even more.
https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download

(This question is more than 10 years old. I got surprised, nobody answered about Pycharm before...)